# My flutter app is not sending any data to my database

Tags: laravel, flutter

I am trying to send data to my database through my flutter app but my flutter app seems not to repond am using laravel as my backend,
the laravel endpoint is working perfectly on postman

flutter code api response class

```
class ApiResponse {
  Object? data;
  String? error;
}
```

constant class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//___STRINGS_____

const baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
const loginUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login';
const registerUrl = '$baseUrl/register';
const userUrl = '$baseUrl/user';
const logOutUrl = '$baseUrl/logout';
const postsUrl = '$baseUrl/posts';
const commentsUrl = '$baseUrl/comments';

//______ERRORS___
const serverError = 'Server error';
const unauthorized = 'unauthorized';
const somethingWentWrong = 'something went wrong try again';
```

laravel endpoint

```
//public routes
Route::post('/register', [Authcontroller::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [Authcontroller::class, 'Login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {

    //user
    Route::get('/user', [Authcontroller::class, 'user']);
    Route::put('/user', [Authcontroller::class, 'Update']);
    Route::post('/logOut', [Authcontroller::class, 'logOut']);

    //post
    Route::get('/posts', [postController::class, 'index']); //all posts
    Route::post('/posts', [postController::class, 'store']); //create posts
    Route::get('/posts/{id}', [postController::class, 'show']); //single posts
    Route::put('/posts/{id}', [postController::class, 'update']); //update
    Route::delete('/posts/{id}', [postController::class, 'destroy']); //destroy

    //comments
    Route::get('/posts/{id}/comments', [commentController::class, 'index']); //all posts
    Route::post('/posts/{id}/comments', [commentController::class, 'store']); //create posts
    Route::put('/comments/{id}', [commentController::class, 'update']); //update
    Route::delete('/comments/{id}', [commentController::class, 'destroy']); //destroy

    //likes
    Route::post('/posts/{id}/likes', [likeController::class, 'likeOrUnlike']); //like or dislike a post



});
```

the user service class allows login ,register and updating user

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:blog_project/models/api_response.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/user.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/constant.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<ApiResponse> login(String email, String password) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(loginUrl),
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
        body: {'email': email, 'password': password});

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        break;
      case 422:
        final errors = jsonDecode(response.body)['errors'];
        apiResponse.error = errors[errors.key.elementAt(0)][0];
        break;
      case 403:
        apiResponse.error = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

// register
Future<ApiResponse> register(String name, String email, String password) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(registerUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }, body: {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'password_confirmation': password
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        break;
      case 422:
        final errors = jsonDecode(response.body)['errors'];
        apiResponse.error = errors[errors.key.elementAt(0)][0];
        break;

      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

//user
Future<ApiResponse> getUserDetail() async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(userUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

//update user
Future<ApiResponse> updateUser(String name, String? image) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(userUrl),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: image == null
            ? {
                'name': name,
              }
            : {'name': name, 'image': image});
    // user can update his/her name or name and image

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        print(response.body);
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

//getToken
Future<String> getToken() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return pref.getString("token") ?? '';
}

//getUserId
Future<int> getUserId() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return pref.getInt('userId') ?? 0;
}

//getLogOut
Future<bool> logOut() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await pref.remove('token');
}

//Get base64 ecoded image
String? getStringImage(File? file) {
  if (file == null) return null;
  return base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
}
```

the post service class

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:blog_project/models/api_response.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/post.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/user.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/constant.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/user_service.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// get all posts
Future<ApiResponse> getPosts() async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(postsUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['posts']
            .map((p) => Post.fromJson(p))
            .toList();
        // we get list of posts, so we need to map each item to post model
        apiResponse.data as List<dynamic>;
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> createPosts(String body, String? image) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(postsUrl),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: image != null
            ? {
                'body': body,
                'image': image,
              }
            : {'body': body});

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        break;

      case 422:
        final errors = jsonDecode(response.body)['errors'];
        apiResponse.error = errors[errors.keys.elementAt(0)[0]];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> editPosts(int postId, String body) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.put(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId'), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    }, body: {
      'body': body
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 403:
        apiResponse.error = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> deletePosts(int postId) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.delete(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId'),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 403:
        apiResponse.error = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> likeUnlikePost(int postId) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.put(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId/likes'),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that's making the requests.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
If I am not wrong, this might not work in iOS.
Anyway please add some code making request and if error please add those logs here.

Comment: @PawanAcharya I have made  the update

Comment: @Allan do you get any error on both app side and server side.

Comment: I cannot see any error message...it seems the app cannot sense the backend

Comment: @Cabdirashiid please check the update I have done

Comment: Try printing response and errors in the catch block. What do they print?